# Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource()

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I just set up a new MODX site, and installed MIGX. I created five TVs, and the containing MIGX tv, and was able to create items on the associated template.

However, when I veiw them on the front end, I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getSource() on a non-object in /home/test/public_html/core/cache/includes/elements/modsnippet/1.include.cache.php on line 122
```

Here's the code on the template:

```
[[!getImageList?
  &tvname='projectMIGX'
  &tpl='tplProjectList']]
```

And here's the tplProjectList code:

```
<div class="projectListItemImage">[[+projectImage]]</div>
<div class="projectListItemTitle">[[+projectTitle]]</div>
<div class="projectListItemLocation">[[+projectLocation]]</div>
<div class="projectListItemDescription">[[+projectDescription]]</div>
<div class="projectListItemStats">[[+projectFundedPercent]]% Funded | $[[+projectFundedAmount]] Pledged</div>
```

My initial thoughts are that this is caused by MODX/MIGX configuration issues on my site, but I can't figure out what.

Any ideas why this is happening? Any additional relevant information I can provide?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Answered my own question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, apparently you have to use the TILDE `` ` `` character in the template. I thought they were single quotes, how silly of me.

Anyhow, after changing them to the tilde character, The code works. Hope this helps some one at a later date!

Comment: Yep, that would be it; MODX is quite forgiving but you need to be careful with the syntax.

Comment: Yeah, I guess in my haste and with my previous experience, I just assumed the weird looking single quotes were a quirk of the font, not an entirely different character! Glad this worked itself out, I was banging my head against the wall for a while there.